# Basic cxfrs RESTful JAX-RS Service

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I am trying to get a basic CXF RS JAX-RS example to work.  Unfortunately, a GET on a resource that I want to return HTML doesn't seem to invoke the resource at all.

Here's an extract from the spring bean:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:9099/route"
              serviceClass="com.example.HelloResource"/>

<bean id="HelloResource" class="com.example.HelloResource"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServer"/>
        <to uri="log:AFTER?showAll=true"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Here is an extract from the corresponding JAX-RS resource:

```
@Path("/")
public class HelloResource {
   private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HelloResource.class);

   public HelloResource() {
       log.info("Creating HelloResource ...");
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/hello")
   @Produces("text/html")
   public String hello() {
       log.info("***** Hello? ******");
       return "<p>Hello World!</p>";
   }
}
```

The following command returns no output:

```
curl localhost:9099/route/hello
```

As you can see from the following log extract, the spring bean is constructed, the method it will call seems correct, but the method doesn't actually seem to be called:

```
14:55:27,614 | INFO  | qtp137557963-131 | HelloResource              | 180 - hello.jar - 0.0.0 | Creating HelloResource ...
14:55:27,616 | INFO  | qtp137557963-131 | AFTER                      | 96 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Exchange[Id:ASDF63648-1398714852208-0-3, ExchangePattern:InOut, Properties:{CamelToEndpoint=log://AFTER?showAll=true, CamelCreatedTimestamp=Mon Apr 28 14:55:27 CDT 2014}, Headers:{CamelHttpUri=/route/hello,CamelCxfMessage=org.apache.cxf.message.XMLMessage@76159b6f, CamelHttpPath=/hello, breadcrumbId=ASDFAS3987148522080-4,CamelCxfRsResponseGenericType=class java.lang.String, User-Agent=curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3,operationName=hello, Accept=*/*, Content-Type=null, CamelHttpMethod=GET, CamelCxfRsOperationResourceInfoStack=[org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.MethodInvocationInfo@354563cc], Host=localhost:9099, CamelAcceptContentType=*/*, CamelCxfRsResponseClass=class java.lang.String},BodyType:org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList, Body:[], Out: null]
```

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong.  I'd appreciate any help someone has to offer ...

Thanks!

Comment: Try testing with SOAP ui it will help a lot.

Comment: I found the answer to my own problem thanks to a link I found [comparing Apache CXF vs. Camel-CXF](http://java.dzone.com/articles/basic-rest-service-apache-cxf). Apparently, I was using the Camel-CXF notation but should have been using the Apache CXF JAX-RS server since I don't need Camel routes.  I still don't understand how the JAX-RS resource is called in Camel-CXF notation, but once I added the <jaxrs:server> notation, it worked.